# How to use Upper/Lower case

Tags: javascript, html

Hey So I had a code like this

```
const answer = "HA"

const answers = answer.toLowerCase();

const theanswer = document.getElementById("WIT").value;

if(theanswer == answers) {
console.log("correct")
}
```

the thing is if the correct only showed up if I type "ha"

How can i make the correct showed if I type "HA" or "Ha" or "hA" or "ha"

Comment: If you are wanting to make the word lowercase, you need to split up the word into an array, and then for each element in the array, convert it toLowerCase() once done, join the array back together

Comment: The answer was given to you. If the answer helped you, then take it as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

To compare the values - convert the value to lowerCase as well - for example - try typing "ha" into the input.

On the first charachrer - "h" - you will log "h: incorrect" and then on the "a" it will log "ha: correct". ay other character s will obviously not match the "HA" and will be incorrect.

```js
const answer = "HA"
const answers = answer.toLowerCase();

document.querySelector('#WIT').addEventListener('keyup', checkMe)

function checkMe(){
  const theanswer = document.getElementById("WIT").value;

if(theanswer.toLowerCase() == answers) {
  console.log(theanswer + ": correct")
  } else {
  console.log(theanswer + ": incorrect")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="WIT" />
```

Comment: I FORGET TO DO THAT